# direct convert XML to XLS

Tags: xml, xls

i have a xml doc (generated from asp + some data from database), here is the sample: http://www.mumugo.ca/Report.xml

now, how do i convert the entire xml to xls?

(my server takes asp, and php)

thx.

Comment: It already looks like XLS. Have you tried opening it in Excel?

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet would be to look at doing an XSL Transformation into a CSV or xlsx file.  you could then load it into excel with either of those formats.